# Log4j - Crea varios logs pero escribe aleatoriamente solo en uno cuando se usa ejecucion en paralelo

Tags: java, groovy, log4j

El problema que tengo es que al usar Log4j durante una ejecución en paralelo de varios procesos, este me crea un log para cada uno de los procesos, pero escribe toda la salida en uno de ellos aleatoriamente.
Esta escrito en groovy.

Este es mi `.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,  INFO, DEBUG

Define which packages use which appenders
Custom Appenderlog4j.appender.customLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.customLogger.File=/dummy
log4j.appender.customLogger.MaxFileSize=3000KB
log4j.appender.customLogger.MaxBackupIndex=15
log4j.appender.customLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.customLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d [%c{1}] (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n
```

Y este mi `logger.groovy`:

```
class CustomLogin {

    def conf
    def log4javaProp

    def getCustomLogger (conf, name)
    {
        Log log = LogFactory.getLog(org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender);

        Properties props = new Properties();

        try {
            if (conf['LOG_CONFIG']['LOG4JAVA'] != null) {
                log4javaProp = "/" + conf['LOG_CONFIG']['LOG4JAVA']
            } else {
                log4javaProp = "/CustomLog4j.properties"
            }
            InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(log4javaProp);
            props.load(configStream);
            configStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(" FATAL: CustomLog4j.propertiess NOT FOUND");
        }

        props.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "INFO, customLogger");

        //Obtener PID
        java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        java.lang.reflect.Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
        jvm.setAccessible(true);

        sun.management.VMManagement mgmt = (sun.management.VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
        java.lang.reflect.Method pid_method = mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
        pid_method.setAccessible(true);

        int pid = (Integer) pid_method.invoke(mgmt);
        //FIN PID

        //Indicamos el nombre del archivo donde se va a guardar el log
        def filepath =  "log/"+conf['LOG_CONFIG']['LOG_DIR']+"/";

        props.setProperty("log4j.appender.customLogger.File", filepath + name + "_" + pid + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log");
        //LogManager.resetConfiguration();
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

    }

    def destroyCustomLogger(conf) {
        org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender("customLogger");
    }
}
```

Estoy lanzando para probar un import con sqoop que hace 3 imports en paralelo y estos son los logs que me escribe:

> 426 Jun 22 11:01 main
>   0 Jun 22 11:01 Sqoop x1.log
>   0 Jun 22 11:01 Sqoop x2.log
>   8356 Jun 22 11:02 Sqoop x3.log

Quiero que escriba la salida de cada uno de los export que se hacen paralelamente en su log correspondiente, y no las 3 salidas juntas en uno de ellos aleatoriamente para cada ejecución.

Comment: Una pregunta Jose, son threads diferentes o ejecutas el proceso tres veces simultaneas ? gracias.

Comment: Es un solo proceso con NThreads.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas en este caso, es un appender por cada Thread o Proceso que ejecutes:

Log4j vive a nivel del Classloader. Entonces, como estás regenerando la configuración para cada uno de los threads, Log4j siempre toma esto como una reescritura de configuración.

Una posible solución es que cada Proceso tenga su propio Appender, para lograr esto, podrías usar el ID del thread. No lo he probado, pero sería algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
class CustomLogin {

   def conf
   def log4javaProp

   def getCustomLogger (conf, name)
   {
       Log log = LogFactory.getLog(org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender);

       Properties props = new Properties();

       try {
           if (conf['LOG_CONFIG']['LOG4JAVA'] != null) {
               log4javaProp = "/" + conf['LOG_CONFIG']['LOG4JAVA']
           } else {
               log4javaProp = "/CustomLog4j.properties"
           }
           InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(log4javaProp);
           props.load(configStream);
           configStream.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new IOException(" FATAL: CustomLog4j.propertiess NOT FOUND");
       }

       def idThread = Thread.currentThread().getId()
       def strCustomAppender = "customAppender" + idThread
       props.setProperty("log4j.currentLogger." +  idThread, "INFO, " + strCustomAppender);

       //Obtener PID
       java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean runtime = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
       java.lang.reflect.Field jvm = runtime.getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
       jvm.setAccessible(true);

       sun.management.VMManagement mgmt = (sun.management.VMManagement) jvm.get(runtime);
       java.lang.reflect.Method pid_method = mgmt.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getProcessId");
       pid_method.setAccessible(true);

       int pid = (Integer) pid_method.invoke(mgmt);
       //FIN PID

       //Indicamos el nombre del archivo donde se va a guardar el log
       def filepath =  "log/"+conf['LOG_CONFIG']['LOG_DIR']+"/";

       props.setProperty("log4j.appender."+strCustomAppender+".File", filepath + name + "_" + pid + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log");
       //LogManager.resetConfiguration();
       PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);

   }

   def destroyCustomLogger(conf) {
       org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender("customLogger");
   }
}
```

Aunque, aún falta agregar la configuración a cada uno de los Appenders, esta configuración la puedes sacar del objeto `props` con cada una de las propiedades que configuras en el archivo properties de la siguiente forma: `props.getProperty('log4j.appender.customLogger.MaxFileSize')`

Comment: Voy a intentarlo asi. Aunque no me queda del todo clara la parte de agregar la configuración a cada uno de los Appenders. Cualquier cosa comento aqui =) gracias!

Comment: No consigo que funcione, solo aparece el main log cuando dejo el código tal cual lo has puesto. Y deja de crear los otros logs

Comment: Tienes que agregar la configuración del appender dentro del ciclo. las configuraciones son `MaxFileSize
MaxBackupIndex
layout
layout.ConversionPattern` y puedes sacarlas del objeto properties que tienes. Por ejemplo, para configurar el MaxFileSize, usarías este código: `props.setProperty("log4j.appender."+strCustomAppender+".MaxBackupIndex", props.get("log4j.appender.customLogger.MaxFileSize"))`

Comment: Añado una respuesta con el código actualizado, aunque aun sin funcionar como espero.